# export teradata result to file adds whitespaces

Tags: unix, teradata

While exporting teradata result to file in unix, it adds whitespaces before the result.

```
bteq << EOF
.logon ....
.SET MAXERROR 4;
.SET RECORDMODE OFF;
.export DATA file=/some/file
select a.cnt||','||b.cnt from
(select count(*) from table1)a,(select count(*) from table2)b;
.EXPORT RESET;
EOF
```

Result:

```
                                                                                       1011,1012
```

The result has a lot of leading spaces. How to remove those spaces and get output like below

```
1011,1012
```

Comment: This can't be returned by your script. You're exporting in DATA mode, thus you'll get binary data, but no readable values like 1011 (you need REPORT mode for this)

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace is due to the Format. Usually when any numeric is converted to string or the field is CHAR (instead VARCHAR). You can either put a TRIM around the field or first put it to a [CSV](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/XOajhd8tmoO~eVPqKNdKSA) inside the RDBMS and export this one CSV-Field.